# Rest client post request, error with multipart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have the following ajax request which works fine, but when i try the same through rest-client ruby gem i'm getting the following error

```
"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Wrong request body. Check if all parameters set correctly\",\"code\":401},\"cartItems\":[]}"
```

JS:

```
    dataContentType = 'application/json'
    data = new FormData
    if dataContentType == 'text/xml'
      data.append 'data', new Blob([ $('#requestXml').val() ], type: 'text/xml')
    else
      data.append 'data', new Blob([ $('#requestJson').val() ], type: 'application/json')
      console.log('requestJson', $('#requestJson').val())
    fileIdx = 0
    $('input[type=file]').each (i, value) ->
      `var i`
      i = 0
      while i < value.files.length
        data.append 'file[' + fileIdx + ']', new Blob([ value.files[i] ], type: 'application/octet-stream'), value.files[i].name
        fileIdx++
        i++
      return
    $.ajax
      type: 'POST'
      url: 'https://imatsandbox.materialise.net/web-api/cartitems/register'
      data: data
      cache: false
      contentType: false
      processData: false
      beforeSend: (request) ->
        request.setRequestHeader 'Accept', dataContentType
        return
      dataType: 'text'
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
```

data variable contains this

```
{"currency":"USD","cartItems":[{"toolID":"toolID","MyCartItemReference":"some reference","modelID":"modelID","modelFileName":"","fileUnits":"mm","fileScaleFactor":"1","materialID":"00e005a8-b29b-4196-ba4e-57ac1c4ce60c","finishID":"bba2bebb-8895-4049-aeb0-ab651cee2597","quantity":"1","xDimMm":81.266,"yDimMm":159.935,"zDimMm":10.096,"volumeCm3":15.5864,"surfaceCm2":260.288,"iMatAPIPrice":"25.0","mySalesPrice":"26.0"}]}
```

I tried with the following using rest client

```
request = RestClient.post("https://imatsandbox.materialise.net/web-api/cartitems/register",{:currency => "USD",:cartItems => [{:toolID => "toolID",:MyCartItemReference => "some reference",:modelID => "modelID",:modelFileName => "",:fileUnits => "mm",:fileScaleFactor => "1",:materialID => "00e005a8-b29b-4196-ba4e-57ac1c4ce60c",:finishID => "bba2bebb-8895-4049-aeb0-ab651cee2597",:quantity => "1",:xDimMm => "81.266",:yDimMm => "159.935",:zDimMm => "10.096",:volumeCm3 => "15.5864",:surfaceCm2 => "260.288",:iMatAPIPrice => "25.0",:mySalesPrice => "26.0"}], :multipart => true})
```

In coffee script it works fine, when i try in the rest client it throws mentioned error.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: How do i set the blob in rest client

Comment: Try sending the post body as JSON string. You can convert the hash to JSON string using `to_json` method

Comment: Can you post the ajax request response as well here...

Comment: @GokulM tried to_json it didnt work

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Added screenshot check if it helps

Comment: @Anbazhaganp response please not the request headers...

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:735
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 12 Jul 2017 13:20:45 GMT
Expires:-1
P3P:policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS UNI PUR COM NAV INT CNT STA"
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Comment: This is the response header, and in response i get the data of uploaded cart

Comment: Can you tell me the version of RestClient you are using...In rails console you can type RestClient.version

Comment: @VamsiKrishna rest client version 2.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149019/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-anbazhagan-p).

Comment: Did you finally solve the problem?